# 'module' object has no attribute 'Player'

Tags: python, class, module, attributeerror

I'm trying to make a simple game, which has multiple files that need to import each other. My mob module needs to import my player module and do player = player.Player() to create a new class instance. The class is in the player.py file, but it's apparently not being recognized.

I did world = world.World() in my mob file, and that worked perfectly, so I'm confused as to why my player file won't work.

```
player.__file__ shows the correct path so that's not the issue.
```

This is what I have at the beginning of mob.py:

```
import world
import main
import player

world = world.World()
player = player.Player()

class Mob:
    #Class definition
```

player.py:

```
import main
import world

world = world.World()

class Player:
    #Definition
```

world.py:

```
import os
import main

class World:
    #Definition
```

Not sure if this will help, but this is the main function in main.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    console = []
    player = player.Player()
    movePlayer = player.Move
    transformPlayer = player.Transform
    goblin = mob.Mob()
    world = world.World()
    mapSize = world.MapSize
    mainMenu()
```

Comment: What do the files and folders look like?

Comment: It's just one folder with main.py, mob.py, player.py, and world.py, plus the .pyc files.

Comment: What's in the files? Post the source code (or at least the imports and the class definitions).

Comment: This is just a guess given the scant information you've provided, but… when you write `player = player.Player()`, you've just hidden the `player` module with a variable of the same name. So, before that statement everything is fine, but after that, you can't access the module anymore. In particular, if you try `player = player.Player()` a second time, it will raise an `AttributeError` exactly like the one you seem to be describing (unless `Player` instances happen to have a member named `Player`).

Comment: mob.py imports world, main, and player, player.py imports main and world, and world.py imports os and main. The class definitions are 40-70 lines each, so I can't really post them.

Comment: @abarnert I made the class instances right after the imports (which are the first thing in the file), so player hasn't been changed until the line that this error is on. I tried changing the name of the instance and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @wipeout4wh: Why don't you actually show us your code? It'd probably make it easier.

Comment: Or, even better than showing us your code, create a stripped-down example that _is_ small enough to post and demonstrates the same problem. (See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for more on this.)

Comment: I've updated my main post with some code, but the entire project is almost 300 lines, so I'm not sure what code to show. The only thing that seems relevant to me is what I posted.

Comment: You may have a [circular import](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-have-modules-that-mutually-import-each-other). If that's so, some modules aren't fully initialized when other modules try to use them to initialize themselves. You may have to restructure your program.

Comment: If I take the code from your post, add a `pass` to each class just to make it compile, create an empty `main.py` file, and run `python mob.py` (with any version of Python), I get no error. So… if that code is enough to demonstrate the error, tell us what you're doing differently from what I did.

Comment: What's this `main` that all your modules seem to be importing? It doesn't sound like the kind of thing you should be importing.

Comment: As a side note, if this is Python 2.x, you shouldn't be creating old-style classes like this; do `class Player(object):`, etc. (This isn't relevant to the problem you're trying to solve, however. And, if you're using Python 3.x, ignore it completely.)

Comment: @user2357112: mob.py and main.py do import each other, but I'm not sure how to go about restructuring that. Also, player.py doesn't import anything but main and world, so I don't see how it would be causing an error in mob.py.

Comment: @user2357112: main has all of the main functions, like mainMenu(), game(), getInput(), etc. It handles everything that doesn't directly involve mobs, the world, or the player. I don't quite understand the concept of OOP yet, so my code structure is probably pretty bad.

Comment: @abarnert: I've updated my post again with something that might be helpful, but I'm not sure if it's really relevant.

Comment: @wipeout4wh: So why does anyone need to import `main` at all? (That may actually be your problem, thanks to the circular import issue that user2357112 pointed out above. But even if it's not your problem, it's generally a bad idea to import things for no reason.)

Comment: Meanwhile, please show the imports for main.py. Or, better, instead of giving us bit by bit as we guess at what more we might need a little bit at a time, either upload the whole thing somewhere, or give us a complete SSCCE that demonstrates the problem, as we've asked for multiple times. Otherwise, after a while, people will get bored or annoyed trying to guess what bit to try to pull out of you next and just stop helping.

Comment: @abarnert: The imports for main.py are player, world, mob, os, time, and random. I looked at my code again, and world.py is the only thing that really needs to import main. It uses a getInput() function from main to get user input to select the size of the map. I guess it might be better to move mapSize() to main? I can upload the entire project, but I'm not sure where I should upload it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is a circular import.

Since you haven't given us enough of the code to actually test this, it's impossible to give the exact details. If you want to see it for yourself, just add a `print` before and after each `import`, and you can see the sequence of events. But it's going to be something like this:

`player` depends on `main`. `main` depends on `mob`. So, when you try to `import player`, before it can run any of its top-level code, all of `mob`'s top-level code has to run. But `mob` tries to create a `player.Player` object at top level. Since `player` is still waiting for `import main` to finish, it hasn't yet run the code to define that class. Hence the error.

[The official FAQ](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-have-modules-that-mutually-import-each-other) has a nice answer on different ways to fix this. In your case, I think there's a simple answer:

Split `main.py` into two separate modules. Take the shared code that everyone else needs to import, and put it into, say, `utils.py`. Leave the top-level program code that needs to import everyone else in `main.py`. Change each `import main` to `import utils`. And that's it; no more circular imports. (This is effectively Matthias Ulrichs's recommendation from the FAQ, but more specific to your situation—and, as it happens, very common among projects created by novices to Python, especially those who are very skilled at languages that have separate import and implementation files.)

If this isn't doable in your case, consider moving some of the global initialization to initialization functions, which you can call after all the `import`s are done. (This is effectively Guido's recommendation from the FAQ.)

Comment: That definitely seems like the issue. I'll look into it more later today and see what I can do. I'm pretty sure I only have one function that would need to be moved into utils, so it shouldn't be too difficult to fix. I know I haven't given a lot of information, so thanks for not giving up.